# How to avoid clipped popups inside a overflow hidden container

Tags: css, safari, overflow, css-position, z-index

I have a custom dropdown which is kind of a colorpicker. The dropdown container has a fixed height with a custom scrollbar script which uses overflow:hidden. If you hover over the single colors inside the dropdown there opens a little popup/tooltip with the name of the color and an image.
Normally I would give these popups a position:absolute and fine.
But this would lead to clipped popups, so - after much research - I use position:fixed and calculate the exact position of it via JavaScript.
Works great ... except in Safari.
Safari keeps clipping the popups despite it's position:fixed.

How can I fix this?

Summary: I have a container with fixed size and overflow:hidden and elements inside of it which should overflow the borders of the container.
Fixed positioning of the popups seem to fix the problem, but not in Safari.

Testsite: https://kryolan.einfach-beginnen.de/shop-product-singlecolors.html
(the dropdown can be seen on the right under the word "Farbauswahl")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a fix. It seems to be a Safari bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160953.
An ancestor of the popup is positioned absolute and has a z-index:0;.
If I set the z-index of this ancestor to unset the unwanted clipping goes away.